# Rails can't connect mysql instance with ssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, google-cloud-sql, mysql2

I'm trying connect Google Cloud SQL with SSL on my Rails APP, use mysql cli with sslca, everything is fine.

```
$ mysql --ssl-ca=config/server-ca.pem --host=instance-ip --user=username --password
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1535
Server version: 5.6.26 (Google)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

This is my database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: username
  password: userpassword
  host: instance-ip
  database: RailsDB
  sslca: config/server-ca.pem
```

When I start rails server and try to access my website it show up

```
Mysql2::Error (Access denied for user 'username'@'my-public-ip' (using password: YES))
```

This confused me, it should be connect to Google Cloud SQL instance IP, but it change to my public IP??

Have any idea? Thanks for your watch

Comment: Ensure only encrypted connections are accepted on server-side. Therefore, run

`GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'encrypted_user'@'%' REQUIRE SSL`

Comment: I'm sure Only secured connections are allowed to connect to this instance. set in Google Cloud SQL console

Comment: The error is saying that MySQL doesn't think 'username' is allowed to connect from ip 'my-public-ip'. Which hosts do you allow for user 'username'?

Comment: User Control in Google Cloud SQL is %(any host), and firewall is set from 0.0.0.0/0